# Stop a function after a thread process is done runnig

Tags: python, tkinter, python-multithreading

i made a little GUI to take input from the user one of the main process is withing a thread and since that command starts there's an event that triggers an endless progress bar to simulate waitting time.

But i want to make it really usefull, but i can't find a way stop the progressbar when the process is done.

so any help on that, would be great.

Comment: In order for people to help you we need a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can place a `return` statement in the code that will be hit when the thread is done